# getting document frequency of a word in Thunderbird emails in Python program

Tags: python, mozilla, thunderbird-addon

I am developing an extension to modify the search functionality of Thunderbird. I have written my program in Python and I want to get document frequency (DF) of words in query from Thunderbird index. I am thinking of getting the DF by querying the global-messages-db.sqlite from my Python program, but I didn't find which table and column stores the text from emails. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: My experience with Thunderbird (which is supported by the [documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird)) is that the mail text is "stored in text files with the folders name and no file extension".

Comment: see https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyThunderbird